# What should I include on line 7 of US form 1040?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

On [U.S. Form 1040](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040gi.pdf), Line 7 says:

> Enter the total of your wages, salaries, tips, etc.

For this line, should I include the portion of my salary used to pay medical and dental premiums?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, you should enter the sum of the salaries on all your W2s, from box 1 on each.

Comment: I missed that, sir.